# How to disable title of bar item in UITabBar (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am developing iPhone Application.I want to disable title of UITabbar.I know that title is the inbuilt property of tabBar Item,But is there any way to disable title and show only image.

I am also attaching screenshot for reference. I don't want title of bar item in TabBar like this :

[image]

> I want to TabBar as below screenshots ,

So that `image is displayed exactly on center of bar item.I tried with setting title to nil but It took the space and image will be displayed little upper side.` :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating the tab bar through code or is it IB or storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look to be a UITabBar, it looks like a custom tab bar control. It might be [TabBarKit](https://github.com/davidmorford/TabBarKit).

There are other custom tab bar controls you can look into also. Have you checked out [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible if you make custome tabBar by adding subItems(just like imageView n Label) on tabBar.
and after seleting tab that delegate(below) call and in this delegate we can change the size of imageview and also hide the label.
these imageview and label are make global.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControll didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{


    if (tabBarControll.selectedIndex==0)
    {
        [yourLabel setHidden:YES];



    [yourimageview setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y, height, width)];


    }
}
```